# Display downloadButton() based on certain condtions in a shiny adashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny dashboard below in which if I give a name except of the default `consent.name`,then the password `makis` and press the `Get started` actionbutton an rmd output is generated. Then the user can press `'Generate report'` in order to download this as pdf. Basically what I want to do is to display the `'Generate report' downloadButton()` only when the report is created and displayed in the body because otherwise it has no meaning and is confusing. I tried to applied the `observeEvent()` method which I used for the report creation as well but it does not work and the `downloadButton()` is always there.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
library(knitr)
mytitle <- paste0("Life, Death & Statins")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(
    div(style = "margin-left:-15px;margin-bottom:-83px;margin-top:-15px;padding: 0px 1190px 0px 0px ; width: 290px;",
        img(src = 'download.png', height = "125px",width="232px")),
    div(style="display: inline;margin-top:-35px; padding: 0px 90px 0px 1250px ;font-size: 58px ;color: black;font-family:Times-New Roman;font-weight: bold; width: 500px;",HTML(mytitle)),
    div(style="display: inline;margin-top:25px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 1250px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("well", "Welcome"))
  ),
  class = "dropdown")
  
  
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Welcome", tabName = "well", icon = icon("house"))
                                           
                               )           ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      tabItems(
        tabItem("well",
                fluidRow(),
                tags$hr(),
                tags$hr(),
                fluidRow(
                  column(5,),
                  column(6,
                         fluidRow(column(3,textInput("name", label = ("Name"), value = "consent.name"))),
                         fluidRow(
                           column(5,),
                           column(6,passwordInput("pwd", "Enter the Database browser password")
                                  
                           )),
                         actionButton("button", "Get started",style='padding:4px; font-size:140%'),
                         
                         fluidRow(
                           column(3,
                                  downloadButton("report", "Generate report",style='padding:4px; font-size:180%')
                           ),
                           column(6,
                                  uiOutput('markdown')
                           )))))
       
      )
      
    )
    
  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    
    observeEvent(input$button,{
      if (input$name=="consent.name"){
        return(NULL)
      }
      else{
        if(input$pwd=="makis"){
          output$markdown <- renderUI({
            HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit('ex.rmd', quiet = TRUE)))
          })
          
        }
        else{
          return(NULL)
        }
      }
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(input$button,{
      if (input$name=="consent.name"){
        return(NULL)
      }
      else{
        if(input$pwd=="makis"){
          
          output$report <- downloadHandler(
            # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
            filename = "report.pdf",
            content = function(file) {
              
              tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "ex.Rmd")
              file.copy("ex.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
              
              rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                                envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
              )
            }
          )
        }
        else{
          return(NULL)
        }
      }
    })
    
    
  }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `renderXXX` functions inside observers is not recommended.

Here is a way:

```
library(shiny)
library(markdown)
library(rmarkdown)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      passwordInput("pwd", "Password"),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "output.passwordOK",
        actionButton("button", "Generate report"),
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "output.reportDone",
        downloadButton("dwnld", "Download report")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("preview")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  # indicator report has been generated
  reportDone <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  output[["reportDone"]] <- reactive({
    reportDone()
  })
  outputOptions(output, "reportDone", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  
  # indicator password is right
  passwordOK <- eventReactive(input[["pwd"]], {
    input[["pwd"]] == "darwin"
  })
  output[["passwordOK"]] <- reactive({
    passwordOK()
  })
  outputOptions(output, "passwordOK", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  
  # generate report preview on button click
  HTMLreport <- eventReactive(input[["button"]], {
    req(passwordOK())
    reportDone(TRUE)
    HTML(markdownToHTML("www/ex.Rmd", output = NULL))
  })
  output[["preview"]] <- renderUI({
    HTMLreport()
  })
  
  # download handler
  output[["dwnld"]] <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.html",
    content = function(file){
      render("www/ex.Rmd", output_file = file)
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal but my app is more complex actually and has to move through different tabs. I accepted that since it answers the original Q but created a more represantive one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65040754/display-download-button-in-a-tab-based-on-actions-in-other-tabs-of-a-shiny-dashb

Comment: the correct link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044981/display-download-button-in-a-tab-based-on-actions-in-other-tabs-of-a-shiny-dashb