# Display download button in a tab based on actions in other tabs of a shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny dashboard below in which if I give a name except of the default `consent.name`, then press `Continue` and will be moved in the tabItem `Password` in which I give the password `makis` and press the `Get started` actionbutton in either `Welcome` or `Run Project` tab an rmd output is generated. Then the user can press `'Generate report'` in order to download this as pdf. Basically what I want to do is to display the `'Generate report' downloadButton()` only when the report is created and displayed in the body because otherwise it has no meaning and is confusing. I tried to applied the `observeEvent()` method which I used for the report creation as well but it does not work and the `downloadButton()` is always there.

the ex.rmd

```
---
title: "An example Knitr/R Markdown document"
output: pdf_document
---


{r chunk_name, include=FALSE}
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(100)
cor(x, y)
```

and the app

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
library(knitr)
mytitle <- paste0("Life, Death & Statins")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(
    
    div(style="display: inline;margin-top:-35px; padding: 0px 90px 0px 1250px ;font-size: 58px ;color: black;font-family:Times-New Roman;font-weight: bold; width: 500px;",HTML(mytitle)),
    div(style="display: inline;margin-top:25px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 1250px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("well", "Welcome")),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("conse", "Consent")),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("pswd", "Password")),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("rp", "Run Project")),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("res", "Results"))
    
  ),
  class = "dropdown")
  
  
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Welcome", tabName = "well", icon = icon("house")),
                                           menuItem("Consent", tabName = "conse", icon = icon("line-chart")),
                                           menuItem("Password", tabName = "pswd", icon = icon("house")),
                                           menuItem("Run Project", tabName = "rp", icon = icon("table")),
                                           menuItem("Results", tabName = "res", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               )           ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      tabItems(
        tabItem("well",
                fluidRow(),
                tags$hr(),
                tags$hr(),
                fluidRow(
                  column(5,),
                  column(6,
                         actionButton("button", "Get started",style='padding:4px; font-size:140%')))),
        
        tabItem("conse",
                tags$hr(),
                fluidRow(column(3,textInput("name", label = ("Name"), value = "consent.name"))),
                fluidRow(column(3,actionButton('continue', "Continue",style='padding:4px; font-size:180%')))
        ),
        tabItem("pswd",
                tags$hr(),
                tags$hr(),
                fluidRow(
                  column(5,),
                  column(6,passwordInput("pwd", "Enter the Database browser password")
                         
                         
                  )) ),
        tabItem("rp"),
        tabItem("res",
                tags$hr(),
                tags$hr(),
                
                fluidRow(
                  column(3,
                         uiOutput("downloadbtn")
                  ),
                  column(6,
                         uiOutput('markdown'))))
      ),
      
      
      
    )
    
  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    
    observeEvent(input$button,{
      if (input$name=="consent.name"){
        return(NULL)
      }
      else{
        if(input$pwd=="makis"){
          output$markdown <- renderUI({
            HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit('ex.rmd', quiet = TRUE)))
          })
          
        }
        else{
          return(NULL)
        }
      }
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(input$well, {
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "well")
    })
    observeEvent(input$conse, {
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "conse")
    })
    observeEvent(input$pswd, {
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "pswd")
    })
    observeEvent(input$rp, {
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "well")
    })
    observeEvent(input$res, {
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "res")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      if (input$name=="consent.name") {
        updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                       selected = "conse")
      }
      else{
        if(input$pwd==""){
          updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                         selected = "pswd")
        }
        else if(input$pwd=="makis"){
          updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                         selected = "res")
        }
        else{
          updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                         selected = "pswd")
        }
        
      }
      
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$continue, {
      if (input$name=="consent.name") {
        updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                       selected = "conse")
      }
      else{
        if(input$pwd==""){
          updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                         selected = "pswd")
        }
        else if(input$pwd=="makis"){
          updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                         selected = "res")
        }
        else{
          updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                         selected = "pswd")
        }
        
      }
      
    })
    
    output$downloadbtn <- renderUI({
      if (input$pwd=="makis" & input$button>0 ) { ##  condition under which you would like to display download button
        downloadButton("report", "Generate report",style='padding:4px; font-size:180%')
      }else{
        return(NULL)
      }
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$report,{
      output$report <- downloadHandler(
        # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
        filename = "report.pdf",
        content = function(file) {
          
          tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "ex.Rmd")
          file.copy("ex.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
          
          rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                            envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
          )
        }
      )
    })
  }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `renderUI` on the server side to display the `downloadButton`.  Then you can use the condition under which you want to display the Generate Report button.  You need to replace `downloadButton` with `uiOutput("downloadbtn")` in the `ui`.  Try this in the server.

```
output$downloadbtn <- renderUI({
      if (input$pwd=="makis" & input$button>0 ) { ##  condition under which you would like to display download button
        
        div(style="display: block; padding: 5px 10px 15px 10px ;",
            downloadButton("report",
                         HTML(" PDF"),
                         style = "fill",
                         color = "danger",
                         size = "lg",
                         block = TRUE,
                         no_outline = TRUE
            ) )
      }else{
        return(NULL)
      }
    })
    
    observe({
      if (input$name=="consent.name"){
        return(NULL)
      }
      else{
        if(input$pwd=="makis"){
          
          output$report <- downloadHandler(
            
            filename = "report.pdf",
            content = function(file) {
              src <- normalizePath('ex.Rmd')
              
              # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
              # permission to the current working directory
              owd <- setwd(tempdir())
              on.exit(setwd(owd))
              file.copy(src, 'ex.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
              
              library(rmarkdown)
              out <- render(input = 'ex.Rmd', 
                            output_format = pdf_document(), 
                            params = list(data = data)
              )
              file.rename(out, file)
              
            }
          )
        }
        else{
          return(NULL)
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: and how this is connected with the downloadhandler()?

Comment: I edited based on your method but I do not think that the button works now.

Comment: Please modify the condition in the statement `if (input$pwd=="makis" & input$button>0 ) {...` to the condition under which you would like the download Button to be displayed.

Comment: but why when I press the download button it does not download anymore, regardless of when the button is displayed?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check the downloadhandler as I am not that familiar with Rmarkdown.  Was that working before?  Please note that my answer was only meant to display downloadButton under certain conditions.

Comment: Maybe u could wit similar logic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65062494/display-loading-message-based-on-specific-click-of-actionbutton-in-a-shiny-app